# SSTable count in Nodetool tablestats(LevelCompactionStrategy)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

One of the tables in my keyspace is using `LevelCompactionStrategy` and when I used the **`nodetool tablestats keyspace.table_name`** command, I get this:

[image].

The command is giving **`SSTable count = 6`** but if you add the numbers shown against **`SSTables in each level`**, then that comes out as 5. Why is there a difference?

Comment: is that consistent or just once?

Comment: I've noticed this several times now. But after sometimes these values change (both values change and become equal. The new value is lesser than before.) and I think this happens only when compaction is going on.